# Adding Page Ordering to a Custom Page Type

Tags: custom-post-types, order

I've created a custom page type (that is, a custom post type converted to a page). This template is used to display profiles of employees.

I then use the [Simple Page Ordering](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-page-ordering/) plugin to order my pages and staff profiles in the custom page template. It works well for my normal pages but isn't working for my custom page template.

I'm not sure what I need to do to make the page ordering work. I noticed my custom page template doesn't have ordering on the edit screen and I'm unsure how to add it - perhaps that would do it?

Here's my archive template markup for my custom pages: http://snippi.com/s/y8288ky

Full functions (in functions.php) for the custom page template: http://snippi.com/s/v0u3h07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple page ordering plugin works by using the `menu_order` setting in the `order_by` settings of a query. [Check it out](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Strange quirk though, when I added orderby they now display in opposite the order I have chosen for them to display in. The first page is the last, the second is the second to last, etc. http://snippi.com/s/hgb6lgr Any input?

Comment: You need to set the order as well such as http://snippi.com/s/jobunzg, descending or ascending